# How to clear pieces of other windows/popups stuck to screen

Tags: terminal

I'm running 8.1.2269 in a terminal on Ubuntu 20.04 (with Regolith).

What sometimes happens, is pieces from other windows, sometimes popups get stuck on the screen. What I mean by this is for example the "refactor conventional commit" text with that background will stay in the same physical spot on my screen regardless of where I navigate in vim. The strange thing is, sometimes the text inside may change. I haven't really figured out why when it happens exactly, but usually, when I start to jump around a lot and ALE and coc.nvim are super busy in the background I think.

I'm looking for a way to clear this without having to exit and reopen vim. A proper solution would also be welcome, but I guess I just have to try and figure out which plugin actually causes this first ...

[image]

Comment: Have you grepped for some error text in the dirs of each applicable plugin? (Unless the errors are coming from a language server in which case, never mind.)

Comment: Is this Vim (not Neovim)? Maybe `:call popup_clear()` will do?

Comment: @BLayer No, I didn't even know plugins log errors separately, I'll take a look!

Comment: @Matt Yes, it is vim. I'll try that the next time I manage to reproduce the error, thanks!

Comment: Also try `:redraw[!]`/Ctrl-L

Comment: Sorry, "error" was probably not the best choice of words. I was referring to the diagnostic messages in the popups such as in your screenshot. Look for that text to identify the plugin (but, as I suggested, that'll only work if it's static text included with the plugin).

Comment: @BLayer, ah I see. They seem to be actually docstring or parts of other buffers, not actually messages ...

Comment: @Matt `:call popup_clear()` actually did the trick! So I guess it _is_ some popup forgotten there by a plugin.