# nvim: how to manually clear popups which do not clear themselves?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, popup

While it may not be the only culprit, [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) is a [bit](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/grbch8/these_annoying_residual_popups/) [notorious](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/30931/25078) for leaving popups hanging around the screen long after they should be cleared. Sometimes, as in the gif below, dangling popups will disappear when the next is instantiated, but in rarer cases, they will hang around for the remainder of the nvim session, which behavior can sometimes necessitate closing and restarting nvim entirely with obvious attendant loss in productivity and organization.

[image: nagging popups]

*small side note for anyone paying close attention: the popup incorrectly stating that `my_first_initial` is defined as a space is a problem with the rust language server and not relevant to this discussion*

vim provides [popup_clear](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html#popup_clear%28%29) as an "[e]mergency solution to a misbehaving plugin", but nvim for some reason does not provide the same functionality. Can someone please point me to an nvim solution for clearing misbehaving popups from the screen?

EDIT: I stumbled across [`winnr`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#winnr()) and [`wincmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:wincmd) in another context and realized that `winnr('$').'wincmd c'`, i.e. close the last window, is a fairly reliable way to do this, provided of course that a popup is open, and also that it is the last window, which it consistently seems to be.

Can anyone expand on this? Is the assumption that an open popup is the last window valid? Is there a more disciplined way to find the correct window to close (and do nothing if there is no popup open)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`api-floatwin` documentation](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#api-floatwin) has this helpful tidbit of information:

> To close [a floating window] use |nvim_win_close()| or a command such as |:close|.
>
> To check whether a window is floating, check whether the `relative` option in its config is non-empty:
>
> ```lua
> if vim.api.nvim_win_get_config(window_id).relative ~= '' then
>   -- window with this window_id is floating
> end
> ```

With this in hand, it's possible to create a user command to manually close all floating windows like so.

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('CloseFloatingWindows', function(opts)
    for _, window_id in ipairs(vim.api.nvim_list_wins()) do
        -- If window is floating
        if vim.api.nvim_win_get_config(window_id).relative ~= '' then
            -- Force close if called with !
            vim.api.nvim_win_close(window_id, opts.bang)
        end
    end
end, { bang = true, nargs = 0 })
```

`vim.api.nvim_tabpage_list_wins(0)` can be used in place of `vim.api.nvim_list_wins()` to only close floats on the current tab page, which might be preferable since plugins rarely leave orphaned popups across multiple tab pages.

Comment: I'd actually figured this out in the context of focusing on the floating window but forgotten about having asked the question. Thanks for the excellent answer! For anyone curious, the focus operation would be `let c = nvim_win_get_config(window_id)` then check `if c.focusable && !empty(c.relative)` and finally `exec win_id2win(window_id) . 'wincmd w'`.